# Check if Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync was handled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I try to solve problem with the Windows Phone Launcher.
I have application and I would like to call another application using the uri and pass it some data. And I would like to know if the second application started. If the application was not started I would like to do some fallback.

Example:

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("secondApp://data/123", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

if (!result)
{
    // Opps. The second application is not installed.
    ShowToast("Oops. The applications is not installed.");
    UseInternalTinyFunctionalityInstead();
}
```

But the result is always true. Even though the second application is not installed. And additionally the windows message box is displayed "Search for app in the Store?  You need to install an app for this task. Would you like to search for one in the Store? yes, no".

- Is it possible to check if the second application was started/ is installed?
- Is it possible NOT to display this dialog?

Thank you.

Myth Rush

Comment: Hi did you end up finding a solution for this?